# confusing output

Tags: c++, return

Below given program prints x = 10 y = 0

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
  int x;
  int y;
public:
  Test (int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
  Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
  Test setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Test obj1;
  obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
  obj1.print();
  return 0;
}
```

but if we replace

```
Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
Test setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
```

with

```
Test &setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
Test &setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
```

output is x = 10 y = 20
Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you return a plain object rather than a reference, you're returning a copy of the object on which you called the method. `setY` acts on that copy (which is a temporary), then the copy is destructed.

When you return a reference, all the calls operate on the same object, so you get the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The first call to `setX()` returns **a temporary copy** of `obj1` and the call to `setY()` modifies the temporary. Subsequent call to `print()` displays the state of `obj1` and since in `obj1` the `y` member variable was never modified it remains zero.

When you replace the return types with references, no temporary copy is made the both calls to `setX()` and `setY()` operate on `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets go back to basis about object oriented programming.

Lets use a metaphor - say a bus.

A bus has certain properties that can be changed - e.g. fuel.

So if you have a function (top up the fuel) you do not need a new bus that is exactly the same as the last one bit with a fuel tank that is full.

So going back to the original question.

```
Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
```

should read

```
void setX(int a) { x = a; }
```

etc.

You have the same object but the fuel may be topped up (or x in this case)

Comment: While the rationale about returning a new bus is good, the pattern of returning the object so its re-usable is still a highly useful pattern and should not be dismissed without discussing its benefits and costs especially when the question directly pertained to doing so.

Comment: What is so difficult in pressing the return key and a semi colon? The benefits apart from the keyboard is that the code say object do this and then object do that.

Comment: "pressing the return key and semi colon" isn't so much as also adding the object name.  However, again, the upside is missed: This strings together a series of operations keyed off an object.

Comment: @JonathanSeng - What upside? The compiler will optimize it. Your debugger will make it easier to find what line of code things go wrong. Is there something wrong with your fingers?

Comment: Down voted because this dismisses out of hand what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

In the First case you are returning the object by value, Hence the copy of object will be created  and returned.
So 
obj1.setX(10) will return a copy of test and than .setY(20) will work on that copy thats why its effects are not on obj1 .

 while in second case a reference to object is returned and hence .setY(20) will work on obj1 itself . Hence the output.

Answer (score -1):

This pinter contain address of a object
In first case
in setx fun this pointer return x  and and not free for return y value at simultaneously therfore he send copy of y not address of y.
In second case
This both function are different both have own this pointer
So they send address of both x and y

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).